# How to implement Music playing custom notification bar on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

I am working on music app and i want to display notification on main screen that xyz music is playing (popup notifucation bar like spotify).

How can i show such popup Notification bar at the end of playlist ? when music is playing and when user click on that bar it will redirect to music playing screen.

When no music is playing that bar get automatically hide and also want to animate that bar during hiding and how can i display it over listview at bottom

as an example please look at below
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/playlist"
            android:layout_above="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgview_album_art"
                    android:src="image"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play_pause"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgview_album_art">

                <TextView
                        android:text="Paradise"
                        android:id="@+id/textview_song_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                        android:text="Coldplay - Mylo Xyloto"
                        android:id="@+id/textview_artist_album"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play_pause"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```